# Youtube API V3 で/feed/subscriptions/activity を取得したい

Tags: youtube-data-api

**Youtube API V3 にて OAuth 認証は済んでいます。**

https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions/activity

自分の登録チャンネルからすべてのアップデートをAPIで取得する方法を
教えていただけないでしょうか？

以下の方法で取得はできているのですが不便なため、他の方法を知りたいです。

登録しているチャンネル一覧から取得：

```
/www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

チャンネルごとに検索し取得：

```
/www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=videoCount&part=snippet&channelId=xxxxxxxxx&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```